# PHP - can't access changed cookie value from the same page

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I'm working on a php project in which i prompt the user to select his city and store it to cookie and then use it to filter the results.

The problem is when i change the city and update the value in cookie from pages other than home page, i can't read the latest value from cookie (note that i'm using jquery cookie plugin and yes,i'm refreshing the page using jquery). But when i check the cookie value from browser tool, it shows the latest value.

Also i notice a thing that when i navigate to other page, i see the change of city there but refresh the same page didn't help.

Note: this project generates dynamic html pages from database using php and i read the cookie from php code $_COOKIE['user_city']

```
    $('#storecity').submit(function(event){
        $frm = $(this);
        var action = $frm.attr('action');
        $city = $frm.find('select[name=city]').val();
        $frm.find('*[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $frm.find('*[type=submit]').attr('value', 'loading...');
        var pageurl = $(location).attr('href');
        $.cookie('user_city', $city, { expires: 365, path: "/"});
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace(pageurl);
    });
```

NOTE : i just now noticed that it works fine in PHP pages only but not in the HTML pages generated which i mentioned above

UPDATE: when i check with $.cookie('user_city') using cookie plugin, the cookie value is changed but not in php $_COOKIE['user_city'];

Answer (score 1):

**Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for.**

This sentence came from [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: i did the page refresh using jquery code, please take a look at my code

Comment: try to replace window.location by location.reload(true); and test cookie

Comment: No change in output. the generated html pages only troubles me

Comment: try to echo `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` this in your php, when you call next HTML page.
I'm sorry i don't get your problem so.